# how to read two stream of items and collect not duplicated items

Tags: algorithm

let's say we have 2 big list or stream of data and we want to read both and collect those items that are only in one stream.

> sample:
>
> list #1 :  1, 4, 5
>
> list #2 :  1, 3, 5, 6
>
> result :  4, 3, 6

Note 1: both lists are too big and we DON'T want to SORT them.

Note 2: items in each stream are unique. so we don't need to worry about duplicate items in a single list

what is the best (fastest) way to do this operation ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's only one pass and the streams are not sorted, it's impossible. Otherwise you could use hash-table, practically it's a bit faster than sort.

Also, look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce approach. If you have really large data, it's good solution for you.

Answer (score 2):

Count how many times each value occurs. Print only values occurring once.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

template<typename InputIterator, typename OutputIterator>
void
uniq (InputIterator b0, InputIterator e0,
      InputIterator b1, InputIterator e1,
      OutputIterator u)
{
  std::unordered_map<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type, int> m;

  while (b0 != e0)
      ++m [*b0++];

  while (b1 != e1)
      ++m [*b1++];

  for (auto &mi : m)
    {
      if (mi.second == 1)
        *u++ = mi.first;
    }
}

int
main ()
{
  std::vector<int> s0 ({1, 4, 5});
  std::vector<int> s1 ({1, 3, 5, 6});
  std::vector<int> r;

  uniq (s0.begin (), s0.end (), s1.begin (), s1.end (), std::back_inserter (r));

  for (auto i : r)
    std::cout << i << " ";
}
```